# share asp.net Identity user class and DbContext class across two project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my application I planned to use asp.net identity to authenticate user into the application.I have separate projects for my domain objects ,Services and a Data project , which holds the generic repository and entity framework Data Context class.I have another two project one for the admin project another one for my End User(Web UI) project.I am using entity framework code first approach.
I created a ApplicationUser class derived from IdentityUser and a ApplicationDbContext class which derived from IdentityDbContext in my admin project's Model folder .I also put the same classes in my WebUI project too.

My problem:

Now I have two ApplicationUser and ApplicationDbContext  class in my two project which doesn't sync when a property is changed in one project.

How do I centralize the the two classes and share across my two application

Comment: You should use a common database to store identity tables, I guess both applications are using an identity database of their own.

Comment: @hazimdikenli , yes I used a common database by passing the same connection string on ApplicationDbContext's constructor

Comment: You should put those classes in a Class Library then, and include them in both of your projects.

Comment: @hazimdikenli , Is I need to create a separate project for those two classes or is  it possible to include those two classes in my existing Domain,Data,Service project

Comment: if your Domain logic is shared between those projects then you can add it to the domain project, otherwise create a new project.

Comment: @hazimdikenli , so If I put the classes into my domain project I need to reference asp.net Identity in my domain project

Comment: Yes, at least you need to implement those interfaces declared by the Identity project. So you need to reference that part of the Identity project (I am not sure but I assume there are different references for the Identity project, so you should not need to include the whole package).